# How to delete files in /System/Library/Desktop Pictures on Catalina?

Tags: macos, command-line, permission, catalina

I tried to delete files in the default desktop picture directory (`/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`) on macOS 10.15 Catalina with `sudo` permission but failed.

```
$ pwd
/System/Library/Desktop Pictures

$ sudo rm *.heic
Password:
rm: cannot remove 'Catalina Clouds.heic': Operation not permitted
```

Is there a hassle-free way to solve this problem?

Comment: How is this a 'problem'? Why do you need to delete them? Just don't use them.

Comment: @benwiggy These wallpapers are taking ~1GB space and I don't need them

Comment: The entire system is only c. 12Gb. If you were to remove all the files that you personally are not going to use, you might save 6Gb at most. I know Apple sells stuff with 128 Gb, but if you need more, then you can use Cloud services or a USB low-profile drive.

Comment: Saving the additional 1GB (and now 2.1GB for me after upgrading to Catalina) really adds up on a 128GB SSD MBP.

Comment: @WillemvanKetwich yeah it's absolutely bonkers that people are challenging OP like this. It's nearly 2% of the usable drive space for unused pictures.

Comment: @benwiggy if the entire system is 12 GB then that means the pictures take up 17.5% of the system. Pictures dude. Probably try to empathize with people who might consider deleting them, what do you think.

Comment: I have enough disk space - I just want to delete unneeded stuff and have more control over the system.

Comment: On a MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014), every GB counts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a general rule I do not recommend deleting *system files*, however, if you really want to remove the *default wallpapers* you can do the following:

1. Boot to **macOS Recovery** by pressing **⌘R** when booting the **Mac**.
2. Using **Terminal**, from the **Utilities** menu, use the following *commands*:

   ```
   cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Desktop\ Pictures
   rm *.heic
   reboot
   ```

Comment: When in recovery mode I can't access such folder. The volum is called "macos base" or something.

Comment: @Nuthinking I realized the same, but now I can't find the Desktop Pictures folder in there.

Comment: I even tried find / *.heic -print but couldn't find any.

Comment: No longer works on Big Sur, the SIP is even stronger. I posted a new answer with details.

Comment: @Mike Hardy, RE: "No longer works on Big Sur" -- The question was specifically and explicitly about **macOS Catalina** and at the time it was posted **macOS Big Sur** had not yet even been announced and didn't exist outside of **Apple** itself and therefore totally irrelevant.

Comment: @user3439894 The answer Mike gave is helpful to me as Google sent me to this page.

Answer (score 7):

Catalina now installs /System as part of a read-only volume, so it cannot be altered whilst in use.

You can modify or delete those files when booted to Recovery, but bear in mind that Apple may well restore them in an update to the OS.

Comment: You said "Catalina now installs /System as a read-only volume, so it cannot be altered.", well`/System` is a directory/folder **not** a volume as you so state, as Macintosh HD is the volume which is mounted at `/` and it **can be altered**!  -- **It can be altered easily from Terminal while booted to macOS Recovery** or from a normal boot if **SIP** has been disabled and the volume remounted with `sudo mount -uw /`. Your answer is completely false and should be deleted!

Comment: ... or edited if someone is willing to do so.

Comment: ... or slightly amended to improve fastidiousness. Whether those actions are done 'easily' is subjective, perhaps.

Comment: @user3439894 `/System` is actually a different volume under the hood in Catalina.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, RE: "`/System` is actually a different volume under the hood in Catalina." -- `/System` **is not** a different volume! `/System` is a **directory** in the _root_ of e.g. **Macintosh HD** and is a part of the **Core.pkg** in the **InstallESD.dmg** in the **Install macOS Catalina.app** _bundle_ which shows is as a directory in the root, it is not a different volume, and the **Core.pkg** is written to the `/` of the **Startup Disk**. You are probably **confused with** `/System/Volumes/Data` which gets mounted, **but** `/System` is a root directory as in previous versions of macOS!

Comment: No longer works on Big Sur, the SIP is even stronger. I posted a new answer with details.

Comment: Worked for me on Catalina.

Answer (score 6):

As of Big Sur this is no longer really feasible.

Why not?

The root filesystem on macOS has been protected strongly forever, with each of the last few OS revisions increasing protections (with SIP, etc)

macOS mounts the System area read-only and as of Big Sur makes sure to only trust it if it has not been changed.

If you violate that trust, certain parts of the system won't work again (specifically: you will not be able to re-enable FileVault afterwards)

If deleting the *.heic files is that important to you though, follow this guide [Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur) (including it's warnings!)

Then from Recovery you may `rm -f *.heic /Volumes/<your hard drive name>/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`

I really wish I had that space back, but I need FileVault more so I gave up.

Comment: There are probably easier ways to regain 1 GB of disk space :-)

Comment: @nohillside, I have to agree and if one is really worried about 1 GB of disk space, then they probably have bigger issues to deal with.

Comment: The question the OP was specifically and explicitly about **macOS Catalina** and at the time it was posted **macOS Big Sur** had not yet even been announced and didn't exist outside of **Apple** itself and therefore this answer is totally irrelevant to the actual question asked.

Comment: @nohillside But whatever easier path you take to save 1 GB of space, you could then save _another_ 1 GB by deleting Desktop Pictures. :D

Comment: @Wowfunhappy An external drive is probably cheaper than going through all the steps required to delete the files (and redoing them after updates)...

Comment: Sure sure - note I downvoted no things :-), just trying to provide current info for current people that show up here. Never assume someone's problems or situation though. I use a lot of OSX-KVM VMs and space is a premium. If you know nothing of people's reasons you should not question their motivation